# Google Apps Script: HtmlService.createHtmlOutput not working in iframe

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe, google-docs

- Create a blank google docs file
- Add the following apps script:

```js
function onOpen(e)
{
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu().addItem('Open dialog', 'openDialog').addItem('Open html', 'openHtml').addToUi();
}
function openDialog() {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('This works');
}
function openHtml() {
    let output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>This works</b>');
    output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Title');
}
```

Now these 2 menu entries appear:

[image]

"Open dialog" works:

[image]

"Open html" works:

[image]

Embed the google docs file in an iframe:

```html
<iframe
   src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit"
></iframe>
```

"Open dialog" works:

[image]

"Open html" does not work:

[image]

Error message in console:

[image]

I thought this is exactly what this line does:

```js
output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

What am I missing?

Here is a link to reproduce that problem:

- [Google Docs with Apps Script](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RHB5LzbthBO6fU9Xc2dAFUSOFbEvlVq6UXobzS_85HQ/edit?usp=sharing)
- [Iframe Embed example](https://jsbin.com/taqalotupa/edit?html,output)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and `"Open html" does not work:`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Can you share with us the whole google apps / html script you used so that we may be able to replicate the issue you encountered and then start from there?

Comment: > Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and "Open html" does not work:. Can I ask you about the detail of it?
The menu entry of "Open html" simply runs the function openHtml().

Comment: > Can you share with us the whole google apps / html script you used so that we may be able to replicate the issue you encountered and then start from there?
I've added a link to the google docs sheet and also to the iframe example.

Answer (score 0):

### Use createHtmlOutputFromFile('filename') Instead

Based on your setup, I found that you just need to link your html script to your google apps script using createHtmlOutputFromFile(). For my test case, I used the following script:

```
function onOpen(e)
{
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu().addItem('Open dialog', 'openDialog').addItem('Open html', 'openHtml').addToUi();
}
function openDialog() {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('This works');
}
function openHtml() {
    var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test.html'); //use createHtmlOutputFromFile instead
    output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
    DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Title');
}
```

On the other hand, I used the same html that you used in your example.

To add your html to the google apps script project, just click on the plus symbol besides "Files". In this test case, I saved your html under the file name "test.html".

[image: Files List]

### Output

[image: iframe]

### Reference

- [Class HtmlService/createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createhtmloutputfromfilefilename)

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried this.
I think you misunderstood the problem: Both createHtmlOutput and createHtmlOutputFromFile work inside the script, if you open it directly: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RHB5LzbthBO6fU9Xc2dAFUSOFbEvlVq6UXobzS_85HQ/edit

The problem arises if I open this docs file *inside* and iframe and open the modal/dialog *inside* there. See (I changed the script to createHtmlOutputFromFile but the problem stays): https://jsbin.com/taqalotupa/edit?html,output